# How to create an array of objects which are NOT move/copy constructible

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constructor

I run into trouble if I would create an array of objects like this:

```
SM sc[8]{{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}};
```

The constructor for SM is defined as:

```
SM::SM(int);
```

Because in c++ `Each member is copy-initialized from the corresponding initializer-clause.` is given, I have a unsolved problem.

I already read:

[Move Constructors and Static Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885479/move-constructors-and-static-arrays)

[Initialization of member array objects avoiding move constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617452/initialization-of-member-array-objects-avoiding-move-constructor)

[Move constructor is required even if it is not used. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678701/move-constructor-is-required-even-if-it-is-not-used-why)

[constexpr array of constexpr objects using move ctor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303650/constexpr-array-of-constexpr-objects-using-move-ctor)

Yes, all the answers describing very well what is giong on with list initialization but I could not found an idea how to get a static array of objects now.

Is there any work around for that problem? Creating a array of pointers and do a runtime initialization with new or new@ operation requires a lot more runtime a memory space. It is a bit problematic because I am on a AVR 8 bit controller.

Comment: You mention "trouble" and "that problem", but never state an actual error.

Comment: The error is: SM::SM(SM&&) is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed: SM::SM(SM&&) = default; A long list of errors go through a long list of subclasses which are inherited from my SM class. Maybe I can shrink down my problem to a full example. But this is not helpful, because the fact that the class can't be copy constructed will remain.

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f67d4683fe50095d).

Answer (score 3):

Just some feedback, in an answer due to code snippets:

Adapting the code at the [3rd link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678701/move-constructor-is-required-even-if-it-is-not-used-why) to:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct SM {
    int val;
    SM(int a) : val(a) { cout <<"Constructor val="<<a<<endl;}
    ~SM() { cout << "Destructor val="<<val<<endl; }

    SM(const SM& ) = delete;
    SM(SM&& ) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    SM sc[8] = { {0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7} };
    return 0;
}
```

compiling with

```
g++ -std=c++11
```

and running, results in:

```
Constructor val=0
Constructor val=1
Constructor val=2
Constructor val=3
Constructor val=4
Constructor val=5
Constructor val=6
Constructor val=7
Destructor val=7
Destructor val=6
Destructor val=5
Destructor val=4
Destructor val=3
Destructor val=2
Destructor val=1
Destructor val=0
```

What exactly is the trouble?

Comment: The trouble is quite simple: My class SM is NOT copy nor move constructable. Your class have a default copy and move constructor defined. For my class both are invalid.

Comment: What are the constructors of your class then?

Comment: @Klaus Like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/628bc19fe40f0358)? If not, you should really add some more code into your question: [M(C)VE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I will look for a full compilable example, but this will take a lot time to walk through my code and shrink. It will be at least tomorrow.

Comment: @Klaus So [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/628bc19fe40f0358) is not what you want?

Comment: Sorry, my problem is that I can NOT compile my code. So it simply can not be reproduced in that way.

Comment: @Klaus Did you try to follow Kenney's answer? This code works for non-copyable, non-movable types.

Answer (score 1):

"copy-initialized" does not mean "calls a copy constructor."

C++14 8.5/15:

> The initialization that occurs in the form

```
T x = a;
```

> as well as in argument passing, function return, throwing an exception, handling an exception, and aggregate member initialization is called *copy-initialization*.

Note that an initializer and an initialized object can have different types.

So you can use an initializer list to initialize an array without necessarily invoking any copy constructor.